# MySql - order by string value first

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table Foobar that looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Description |
+----+-------------+
| 12 | aab         |
+----+-------------+
| 13 | fff         |
+----+-------------+
| 14 | fff         |
+----+-------------+
| 15 | xab         |
+----+-------------+
```

What I would like is to print out all the descriptions in order.  However I would first of all like the values "fff" to be right at the top.  In other words the output should be as follows: fff, fff, aab, xab.

So a simple: "SELECT foobar.description FROM foobar ORDER BY foobar.description ASC" will not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In MySQL this works

```
SELECT foobar.description 
FROM foobar 
ORDER BY foobar.description <> 'fff',
         foobar.description ASC
```

But generally you can also use a `case`

```
SELECT foobar.description 
FROM foobar 
ORDER BY case when foobar.description = 'fff' then 1 else 2 end,
         foobar.description ASC
```

Comment: The query optimizer will probably make no difference between the both. It is only a matter of syntax. The first query syntax works only in MySQL. The latter works for all DB engines and is more portable. But the performance makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
select foobar.description from foobar
order by case when foobar.description = 'fff' then 1 else 2 end,
foobar.description asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT description
FROM foobar
ORDER BY description != 'fff', description
```

This works because in mysql, true is 1 and false is 0.

I have also removed all unnecessary characters from the query.